# Filling nan values if unique conditions on multiple columns are met in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, unique

> I want to fill col3 nan values if the combination of col1 and col2 are matched in another row (but only once). For example: on row 2, since col1 and col2 are both cat, then fill col3 with 'George'. On row 4, since col1 and col2 are Cat and Dog, then fill col3 with Matt

> However, if the combination has occurred more than once like in rows 5 and 7, then ignore don't fill nan with anything.

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | Cat | George |
| Cat | Cat | nan |
| Cat | Dog | Matt |
| Cat | Dog | nan |
| Parrot | Elk | John |
| Parrot | Elk | nan |
| Parrot | Elk | Ryan |
| Parrot | Elk | nan |

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | Cat | George |
| Cat | Cat | *George* |
| Cat | Dog | Matt |
| Cat | Dog | *Matt* |
| Parrot | Elk | John |
| Parrot | Elk | nan |
| Parrot | Elk | Ryan |
| Parrot | Elk | nan |

> I hope this makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can first get the sizes of each group `col1, col3`. Then those of size two we use `ffill` on:

```
sizes = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col2'].transform("size")
df.loc[sizes <= 2, "col3"] = df.loc[sizes <= 2, "col3"].ffill()
```

```
     col1 col2    col3
0     Cat  Cat  George
1     Cat  Cat  George
2     Cat  Dog    Matt
3     Cat  Dog    Matt
4  Parrot  Elk    John
5  Parrot  Elk     NaN
6  Parrot  Elk    Ryan
7  Parrot  Elk     NaN
```